# Why is there a memory leak in GameCenterManager.m?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, selector, game-center

I am using Game Center in my app and I found that the gamecentermanager.m file causes a memory leak:

```
- (void) callDelegate: (SEL) selector withArg: (id) arg error: (NSError*) err
{
assert([NSThread isMainThread]);
if([delegate respondsToSelector: selector])
{
    if(arg != NULL)
    {
        [delegate performSelector: selector withObject: arg withObject: err];
    }
    else
    {
        [delegate performSelector: selector withObject: err];
    }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Missed Method");
}
}
```

The leak happens (according to the compiler warning triangles) because the *performSelector* (both of them) selector is unknown.  there are 2 things I want to know

1) I copied this straight from the example on Apple's website, so wouldn't the code not present an error if Apple built it?

2) How can I fix this?

Just as an FYI, I'm using Xcode 4.3.1 using LLMV Compiler 3.1 and the standard (armv7) Architecture.  I am also using ARC.

If you need any other information just let me know and thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is ARC cannot tell what the memory management semantics are of the method you're calling with `-performSelector:withObject:`. Under MRR, it didn't matter, because the calling code was expected to deal with it accordingly (e.g. by releasing the return value if it was an owned object). But under ARC the compiler *needs* to know this information to be correct. I don't remember what its default behavior is with `-performSelector:withObject:`, it may just be to treat it as a non-owned reference, in which case you're not actually leaking.

The simplest way to deal with this sort of delegate pattern is to still use `-respondsToSelector:` but then to just call the method directly, e.g.

```
if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(foo:)]) {
    [_delegate foo:self];
}
```

In your case, the method itself doesn't actually know what the selector is. Your best bet is probably to ditch this method entirely and let its former callers deal with talking to the delegate.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to add a "fake" category to NSObject declaring this method? Just to "spell out" the semantics...

Comment: @nielsbot: The problem isn't a lack of declaration for the method. The problem is the compiler doesn't even know what method he's trying to call, regardless of declaration, because he's using a dynamic selector to call it.

Comment: I have decided not to continue using the GameCenterManager file that I copied from Apple because of what you said. Thank you for the answer.